# HtmlService loading async sample code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

In the [HtmlService docs async sample code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#load_data_asynchronously_not_in_templates)...

How does the parameter `things` get passed into the function `showThings(things)` after the page loads?

Running as is, the html list just gets emptied.

In my Code.gs, I added in...

```
function getLotsOfThings() {
  return [1,2,3];
}
```

but it doesn't pass or store the result so `showThings()` can use it.

Comment: works fine for me
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page')
      .evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}
function getLotsOfThings() {
Logger.log('was called')
return [1,2,3];
}

Comment: yeah, i see how `getLotsOfThings()` gets called, but not how `showThings()` is ever sent `things`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in `google.script.run` does this for us.

You can think that the Apps Script platform gets the return value of your server-side function `JSON.stringify` it and then `JSON.parse` on the client-side normally. And since `withSuccessHandler` receives you return function, running it and passing a parameter is easy. As [shown by Frits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712894/htmlservice-loading-async-sample-code/19712944#19712944).

Here is what the `withSuccessHandler` [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#success_handlers) says:

> Because client-side code continues to the next line without waiting
>   for a server call to complete, the google.script API allows you to
>   specify another client-side function to run when the server responds.
>   If the server function returns a value, the API passes the value to
>   the new function as a parameter.

By the way, the code example worked just fine for me. Have you had any problems? This is the code I used (plus the example exact html file, which I called "page"):

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page');
}

function getLotsOfThings() {
  return [1,2,3];
}
```

Comment: was using `createTemplateFromFile()` and missing the non-visible API pass concept.

Comment: `createTemplateFromFile` should work too. It's just not necessary since there's nothing to be evaluated on that html example. Actually, that's the main idea of doing asynchronous work. The same page should load faster when using "createOutput..." instead of "createTemplate...", specially because the can cache the cajoling part and not have to redo it every time (which they can't avoid when you createTemplate).

Answer (score 0):

I think that might be a mistake.

It can still work though, see this example:

```
function foo(arg) {
    console.log(arg);
}
function run(callback) {
    callback("bar");
}
run(foo); // "bar"
```

From the code it's not obvious what the value of `things` is though, or where it comes from.

Comment: yeah i'm trying to find out where `things` comes from or what the assumptions are